# ¿Cómo obtengo la session id de un usuario estando logeado con otro usuario? PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mvc, phpmyadmin

Resulta que uno de los requerimientos del sistema que estoy desarrollando es cerrar las sesiones de un usuario cuando a este se le restablezca la contraseña.

Me explico:

- Un administrador es quien tiene la opción de restablecer la contraseña de un usuario, es decir, el usuario vuelve a tener la contraseña por default que le da el sistema.
- El requerimiento pide que cuando se haga click en esta opción, el sistema cierre la sesión (o sesiones) abierta que tenga el usuario.

He intentado obtener el session_id del usuario a quien debo cerrar la sesión (logout) de distintas maneras, pero no encuentro la forma que pueda hacer.

Esta es la parte de JS donde se hace click en el botón para restablecer la contraseña:

```
$('#tabla_persona').on('click', '.resetear_password', function () {
  var data = t_persona.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
  if (t_persona.row(this).child.isShown()) {
    var data = t_persona.row(this).data();
  }
  Swal.fire({
    title: '¿Esta seguro de restablecer a la contrase\u00f1a por default?',
    text: "No podrás revertir esto!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Si, restablecer!'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../controlador/persona/controlador_persona_restablecer_contra.php",
        data: {
          id: data.usuario_id
        },
        }).done(function (resp) {
          if (resp == 1) {
            Swal.fire({
              icon: 'success',
              title: 'Contrase\u001a restablecida',
              showConfirmButton: false,
              timer: 1500
            })
            
            t_persona.ajax.reload();
          } else {
            Swal.fire({
              icon: 'error',
              title: 'Ocurrio un error',
              showConfirmButton: false,
              timer: 1500
            })
          }
        }
      )}
  })

})
```

Esta es la parte HTML donde está el botón para **logout**:

```
<div class="form-group">
                                
                                <button id="btnActualizarContra" type="submit" class="btn btn-default submitBtn" onclick="editarContra_profile_2()">Actualizar</button>

                                <a id="cerrarXcontra" hidden class="dropdown-item" href="../controlador/usuario/controlador_cerrar_sesion.php"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>Logout</a>

                            </div>
```

Lo que pensé inicialmente era con el JS llamar al evento click y pasar los parámetros de la sesión al HTML para el **logout**, sin embargo, no he podido hasta ahora. Tampoco sé si se puede hacer totalmente, según vi se tiene que llevar un control de las sesiones en una tabla en la base de datos para que sea mucho más sencillo, pero realmente no estoy seguro.

Gracias de antemano a todas las respuestas

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135724/discussion-on-question-by-lsanchezo-como-obtengo-la-session-id-de-un-usuario-es).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final resolví el problema de la siguiente manera:

1. No existía una manera en la que un usuario pueda saber si existen sesiones abiertas de otros usuarios debido a que no hay una gestión de las sesiones que se inician, por tanto, se debe crear y hay distintas formas, como usando COOKIES; opté por crear una tabla en la base de datos que lleva la siguiente estructura:

[image: Tabla sesiones]

2. Una vez creada la base de datos procedí a realizar los procedimientos almacenados correspondientes, ya que, para el modelo MVC que uso en el desarrollo del servicio web me resulta eficiente hacer uso de ellos. Los mismos se denominan:

- **SP_REGISTRAR_SESION**

```
INSERT INTO sesiones(sesiones.id_usuario, 
                     sesiones.id_sesion) 
VALUES(IDUSUARIO, IDSESION);
```

- **SP_LISTAR_SESION**

```
SELECT sesiones.id_usuario, CONCAT("sess_", sesiones.id_sesion) AS id_sesion FROM sesiones 
WHERE sesiones.id = (
SELECT MAX(sesiones.id) FROM sesiones 
WHERE  sesiones.id_usuario=IDUSUARIO
);
```

3. Una vez terminado la parte de la base de datos, procedí a configurar el código, para ello realicé modificaciones en dos modelos creando las siguientes funciones:

```
    function registrar_sesion($idUsuario, $idSesion) {
        $sql = "call SP_REGISTRAR_SESION('$idUsuario','$idSesion')";
       
        if ($consulta = $this->conexion->conexion->query($sql)) {

            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
                return $respuesta = trim($row[0]);
            }

            $this->conexion->cerrar();
        }

    }
```

```
 function listar_sesion($id){
            $sql = "call SP_LISTAR_SESION('$id')";
            $arreglo = array();

if ($consulta = $this->conexion->conexion->query($sql)) {
                while ($consulta_VU = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta))
                        $arreglo[] = $consulta_VU;
            }

            return $arreglo;

$this->conexion->cerrar();

        }
```

4. Antes de pasar a la "parte clave", primero se realiza el registro del `session_id()` en la base de datos acompañado del **id_usuario**, para ello (en mi caso) modifiqué mi controlador que quedó de la siguiente forma:

```
$idUsuario=$_SESSION['S_IDUSUARIO'];
    $idSesion=session_id();

    $MU = new Modelo_Usuario();
   
    $consulta = $MU->registrar_sesion($idUsuario, $idSesion)
```

Y así es como se van registrando las sesiones:

[image: Registro de sesiones en base de datos]

5. Esta parte es muy específica porque mi problema era que debía cerrar sesión de aquel usuario a quien se le restablecería su contraseña, en otros casos esto cambiará y tienen que identificar la parte del código JavaScript (en mi caso usé este lenguaje) que realicé dicha acción, por tanto mi código lo modifiqué y use AJAX para ello, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#tabla_usuario').on('click', '.restablecer_contra', function () {
  var data = t_usuario.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
  if (t_usuario.row(this).child.isShown()) {
    var data = t_usuario.row(this).data();
  }
  Swal.fire({
    title: '¿Esta seguro de restablecer a la contrase\u00f1a por default?',
    text: "No podrás revertir esto!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#854c35',
    cancelButtonColor: '#868e96',
    confirmButtonText: 'Si, restablecer!'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../controlador/persona/controlador_persona_restablecer_contra.php",
        data: {
          id: data.usuario_id
        },
      }).done(function (resp) {
        if (resp == 1) {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Contrase\u001a restablecida',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500
          })
          // t_persona.ajax.reload();
          listar_usuario();
          console.log(data.usuario_id);
         
          $.ajax({
            url: "../controlador/persona/controlador_cerrar_sesion_PR.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              id: data.usuario_id
            }
          }).done(function (resp) {
            var data = JSON.parse(resp);          
          })

        } else {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Ocurrio un error',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500
          })
        }
      }
      )
    }
  })

})
```

> **Nótese** que en la petición AJAX clave es la que ejecuta el controlador siguiente: `./controlador/persona/controlador_cerrar_sesion_PR.php`

6. Ahora mostraré el controlador modificado que mencioné previamente.

```
require '../../modelo/modelo_persona.php';
   
    $MP = new Modelo_Persona();
    $id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
   
    $consulta = $MP->listar_sesion($id);
    $sess_path = session_save_path();
    $filename = $sess_path."/".$consulta[0][1];
    unlink($filename);
   

    echo json_encode($consulta);
```

> Hay que fijarnos bien en que se retorna un **array** en la variable `$consulta` (mirar bien la función que `registrar_sesion`). Esto también puede modificarse, en mi caso lo hice así porque todo el servicio web me acostumbré a trabajarlo con arrays y por ello me resultó muy fácil adaptarlo a este problema.

> Luego fijarse bien en que la variable `session_save_path()` es la ruta donde se guarda los archivos temporales que crea PHP para registrar las sesiones activas, por tanto, la lógica a realizar es eliminar ese archivo temporal haciendo uso de `unlink()` colocando entre paréntesis la ruta del archivo, tal cual se muestra en el código.

7. Por último (y para darle un toque más estético) hay que hacer que el usuario a quien se le cerró la sesión también se le recargue la página **(reload)**. Para ello pueden usar el `header()` de PHP o también JavaScript con comandos como el famoso `window.location.reload()`, particularmente opté por este último quedándome la condicional de la siguiente forma:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['S_IDUSUARIO'])) {

echo "<script>window.location.reload();</script>";
exit();

}
```

> Tienen que colocar esta condicional una vez el `session_start()` haya sido inicializado, en mi caso se inicializa en el `index.php` de mi servicio web.

Bueno, eso fue todo, me queda agradecer a [@masterguru](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/263200/masterguru) por la ayuda brindada para desarrollar la solución. Espero pueda servirle a alguno de la comunidad. Saludos!

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. Muy bien redactada, detallada y clara :-)  Muchas gracias por tu aporte a la comunidad!